# Singular/plural keyword search not working

Tags: solr

I am facing a problem with singular and plural keyword search.
For example, if I search men, it should return "men" and also "man". However, it is not working.

Comment: Could you please share the field and its fieldtype in detail...what is there in the fieldType like what tokenizer, filter been used...

Comment: You can define synonym words in your [CORE]/conf/synonyms.txt file

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a SynonymFilter with those terms that you're aware of - the hard part is thinking of every alternative.

While you usually use stemming to get the common stem for words, this problem is known as lemmatization - where you're interested in the different forms of a word, and not the common stem.

For Solr your best bet is probably to be to go for something like [Solr Lemmatizer](https://github.com/nicholasding/solr-lemmatizer) by Nicholas Ding.